# Commonest rounding algorithm for IEEE754 floating point

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

The IEEE754 standard defines five rounding rules. The first two round to a
nearest value (ties to even, ties away from zero); the others are called directed roundings:  towards zero, towards positive infinity and towards negative infinity.
Which one of them is used most often and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most often used mode is the default mode: round to nearest, tie to even.

Why? it's only a guess but:

- minimizing the errors: directed rounding can have up to 1 ulp rounding error versus 1/2 ulp for round to nearest
- avoiding rounding bias: tie away from zero might create a bias when thousands of rounding will be chained

Comment: can you please provide some an example for the _directed rounding can have up to 1 ulp rounding error versus 1/2 ulp for round to nearest_ ?

Comment: @Maximus Suppose you are rounding up and add `1.0+1e-300`. The real number arithmetic result is **very** slightly greater than 1.0. In round up, the error would be `1 ulp - 1e-300`, almost a ulp. In round-to-nearest the error is `1e-300`. Similarly, consider rounding down and subtracting a tiny number from a representable number.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223778/is-bankers-rounding-really-more-numerically-stable