# PHP : Format Currency Issue

Tags: php, intl, currency-formatting, numberformatter

```
numfmt_format_currency(new NumberFormatter('en',2), 31.005, "USD")
```

This code outputs $31.00. But it should output $31.01.

It appears to me that PHP is ignoring to convert 0.005 to 0.01 when it comes to price format.

I was trying to fix Magento's currency format issue and I'm running into this problem on the PHP side.

Comment: try `number_format()`

Comment: `NumberFormatter()` has a number of rounding options. A note elsewhere suggests that it defaults to `ROUND_HALFEVEN`, so it rounds towards the even neighbour. I read that as meaning that your example code for 31.015 would round to 31.02. You could change it to `ROUND_HALFUP` which on the face of it seems like a more sensible default.

Comment: @droopsnoot The `ROUND_HALFEVEN` mode (aka "banker's rounding") is [commonly used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223778/is-bankers-rounding-really-more-numerically-stable).

Comment: As a side note, I found that in JS `Intl.NumberFormat()` the default is the `ROUND_HALFUP` equivalent ({[`roundingMode
: "halfExpand"}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#roundingmode)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

31.005 is actually between two numbers, see *Floating Point Precision* on https://php.net/float .

```
> ini_set('precision', 23)
= "14"

> 31.005
= 31.00499999999999900524
```

*(There is no number 31.005 in PHP -- and other languages.)*

You need to provide the number with enough precision but as little error as necessary to match your display requirements.

This works by specifying the *rounding mode*, when you want 31.005 to be rounded to 31.01, that is [*up*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#numberformatter.constants.round-up) or [*halfup*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#numberformatter.constants.round-halfup).

```php
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

$formatter->setAttribute(
    NumberFormatter::ROUNDING_MODE, 
    NumberFormatter::ROUND_HALFUP
);


echo $formatter->formatCurrency(31.005, 'USD'), "\n";
# Output: $31.01
```

This is what [droopsnoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11649498/droopsnoot) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76825595/php-format-currency-issue/76825896#comment135439137_76825595) about.

### Number Formatter Default Mode and Creation

As [Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12763954/olivier) [reminded in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76825595/php-format-currency-issue/76825896#comment135439461_76825896), the default mode is [*halfeven*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#numberformatter.constants.round-halfeven), also known as [banker's rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223778/is-bankers-rounding-really-more-numerically-stable).

Also they remark that it *"would be cleaner to use explicitly"* the class constant [NumberFormatter::CURRENCY](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#numberformatter.constants.currency) over of the [magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518938/367456) *2*.

```php
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en', 2);
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
```

This will make your code communicate better, otherwise the *2* might be read as number of digits or precision, which is not the case here. You can find all [*style constants*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#intl.numberformatter-constants.unumberformatstyle) in the PHP manual.

---

**Remark:** This is nothing PHP specific, when you pass those numbers to javascript and then need to format them in Javascript, you run into the same.

Cf. Answer to [*"Rounding in JavaScript does not give the same result as in PHP?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76612437/367456).

Comment: By default, the `ROUND_HALFEVEN` mode is used (it's known as [banker's rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223778/is-bankers-rounding-really-more-numerically-stable)).

Comment: It would be cleaner to use explicitly `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` instead of `2`.

Comment: @Olivier: Thanks for these insightful remarks, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful explanation. It worked for me! Thank You @hakre